# Fail to read user with 'OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications' protocol using admin sdk APIs

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-workspace, google-apis-explorer, server-to-server

We are trying to implement OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications
Final motive is to call Google API to read GSuite Users.

Google documentation for OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications is ..
- https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

API to read list of GSuite Users - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/list

As per documentation we may use "Google APIs Client Library" or "HTTP/REST"
However our requirement is to use HTTP/REST.

We have Successfully completed below steps .

1. Creating a service account.
2. Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account.
3. Authorized API call with HTTP/REST.

We are successfully able to get "access token" through POSTMAN after step 3 above.

Postman request to get access_token is successful as below .

```
HTTP POST request :https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

Body parameters: 
grant_type:urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion:The JWT, including signature. 

successful response :
{
"access_token": "ya29.c.EmmOB0vXrihl6nkZNr2gS1nKc4LypBlg3I1bZL2BUvPfZ53rs91fSA2TXR25TvtrZb551sdg1WwHnxg5VYWVC-SEveeypZebfwvhdGr9ECXCeuwAmfyV8TDUIN5nsqbZ7IxVyzgkew",
"expires_in": 3600,
"token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

However getting errors/exceptions While "Calling Google APIs"

Errors while calling API with  access_token which we got .

```
1.Get Request via POSTMAN : Read all GSuite users  
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/?customer=my_customer
Header:Bearer ya29.c.EmmOB0vXrihl6nkZNr2gS1nKc4LypBlg3I1bZL2BUvPfZ53rs91fSA2TXR25TvtrZb551s dg1WwHnxg5VYWCVC-SEveeypZebfwvhdGr9ECXCeuwAmfyV8TDUIN5nsqbZ7IxVyzgkewfZ0

error response :
{
 "error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "backendError",
            "message": "Service unavailable. Please try again"
        }
    ],
    "code": 503,
    "message": "Service unavailable. Please try again"
 }
}
```

2.Get Request via POSTMAN : read GSuite Groups

```
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/? 
customer=my_customer
Header : Bearer ya29.c.EmmOB0v-Xrihl6nkZNr2gS1nKc4LypBlg3I1bZL2BUvPfZ53rs91fSA2TXR25TvtrZb551sdg1WwHnxg5VYWCVC-SEveeypZebfwvhdGr9ECXCeuwAmfyV8TDUIN5nsqbZ7IxVyzgkewfZ0

error response :
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "notFound",
            "message": "Domain not found."
        }
    ],
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Domain not found."
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't need to pass request parameter customer. Try like this

https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/my_customer

more on this [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/get)

and https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/my_customer

more on this [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get)

Comment: Thank you for your response Vaspoor.

I already used parameter customer=my_customer while reading list of users/groups , this parameter we may send in HTTP header or in URI itself. 
I have tried both the options as mentioned in my original description .

API to get list of users  https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list.

API to get single user - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get ( Which you mentioned in your description )